# Memory increase with TableView

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, memory

first of all apologize for my English.
I have a problem it takes days giving me problems.
In the same view I have two tableviews, which when you select an option from the tableview1 shows the items in the tableview2.
The articles are displayed correctly, but the problem is that by using the option Allocations analyze shows me that the memory is increased, ie choose tableview1 and load the objects in memory tableview2 and grows, press other choice items correctly shows me previous articles but does not free memory and increases while new items.

In addition, I have a label with an opacity of 20% and each time you select a category in the tableview1, the label increases by 20% opacity, it is as if they were overlapping.

[TableViewController1 -- ListaCategoriasViewController.m](http://pastie.org/2722906)

[TableViewController2 -- ListaArticulosViewController.m](http://pastie.org/2722921)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I can see: you do some string allocation using stringWithFormat, this string is an autoreleased string but for this to work you have to use an autorelease pool.

this is a problem I have noticed in the ListaArticulosViewController.m in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You have to guard your code where you use autorelease object with an autorelease pool:

```
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init;
 ...  your code  ...
 [pool drain];
```

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath.

In the same area I can see that you allocate some images (UIImage) but you never release them.

Comment: Thank you, I only find one UIImage that i hadn't released.
I'm gonna try your answer :D

Comment: most probably you have some other parts of code where you have to check for problems. this is only what i quickly figured out.

Comment: some other issue: in the viewDidLoad you allocate some NSMutableArray but you never deallocate them. The viewDidLoad is called each time you load the view so this will lead to a memory leak

Comment: I would move this array allocation from viewDidLoad to the init method. If there is another object keeping a reference to your view you will end up allocating this arrays multiple times without deallocating them (even if you put the deallocation in the dealloc).

Comment: I'm going crazy, I checked and I think I release all objects and do what I say but still not working.
I leave my project if you can take a look.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17758189/cosmetica.zip

Comment: Ok, I will have a look when i reach home.

Comment: this is my first big application and i would like learn my mistakes and how make it better

Comment: I did what you said, what to put in the init arrays and not viewDidLoad.
Also, instead of going from an object as the managedObjectContext by all classes I get through SharedApplication.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17758189/cosmetica2.zip

Comment: I fit it!!!!!

I did that you said me and i add this line :

    for (UIView *subview in [[cell contentView] subviews]) 
    {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

http://pastie.org/2728309

Comment: I tried to run your application but i did not manage to get to the 2 view controlers with problems. But I'm glad that you manage to solve the problem. The thing is that when you switch to the next view the previous one is not automatically destroyed and his dealloc is not called, so sometime you have to do this manualy. But I was wrong in one of my previous comments in regards to viewDidLoad.